# Deleting columns based on their names

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame with column names such as
id_1 id_2 id_3 ty yu io

I want to delete columns from dataframe using like condition from sql ; delete columns like 'id%' and few of them by mentioning their position;delete[6] i.e io column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.filter` to filter the columns based on `regex` and then drop those columns from the original dataframe.

```
df.drop(columns = df.filter(regex='id_[0-9]+', axis=1).columns)
```

To delete column by position, you can simply do

```
df.drop(df.columns[index], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan, index=range(3), columns=['id1', 'id2', 'col3','id4', 'col5'])
print(df)
#    id1  id2  col3  id4  col5
# 0  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
# 1  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN

# filter by begining of the column name
df_filtered_by_id = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('id')]
print(df_filtered_by_id)
#    id1  id2  id4
# 0  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN

# filter by positional indices of columns
indexes = [2, 4]
df_filtered_by_index = df.iloc[:, indexes]
print(df_filtered_by_index)
#    col3  col5
# 0   NaN   NaN
# 1   NaN   NaN
# 2   NaN   NaN
```

**UPDATE**

If you would like to use ranges and standalone indices together you can do following:

```
import itertools

indices = [0, 2, range(3, 5)]
indices_flattened = list(itertools.chain(*map(lambda x: [elem for elem in x] if isinstance(x, range) else [x], indices)))
df_filtered_by_combined_types = df.iloc[:, indices_flattened]
print(df_filtered_by_combined_types)
#    id1  col3  id4  col5
# 0  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
# 1  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
# 2  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This sound good; one more query what if; I want to specify range for ex:indexes = [2, 4,6:10]
df_filtered_by_index = df.iloc[:, indexes]
print(df_filtered_by_index).....I mean like specifying indexes and range together in columns drop

Comment: Hello @Rudra! Added update section to cover that case.

Comment: no it did not....I have a huge number of columns, specifiying range[4-7],range[11-15] and so on..becomes tedious and lengthy. and it says it doesnt support the method and throws error

Comment: Try to use range() instead of range[].